# Variables getting overwritten in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I have an array called `$products` with various product data, and an array called `$discounts` where the keys are product item numbers. As I loop over `$products` I wanted to define a local variable that will make access to a particular discount easier, like so:

```
foreach ($products as $prod) {
    $discount = $discounts[$prod->item_number];
    // do stuff
}
```

After too much debugging, I have ascertained that for some reason the above code results in the last item of `$discounts` getting overwritten with the contents of the previous item.

what could possibly cause this strange phenomenon, and how could I give `$discounts[$prod->item_number]` a shorter name without causing it?

Comment: Are you using references anywhere?

Comment: Are you sure, that the last item of `$discounts` gets overwritten and not just `$discount`? In this case, `$discount` always gets overwritten, by the newer var, because it's just a normal var.

Comment: I have literally deleted the entire loop except for that line and then dumped the entire `$discounts` array in every iteration. The second last iteration somehow overwrites the contents of the last item of `$discounts`.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever something strange like this starts happening, I always make sure that [Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) hasn't been "accidentally" enabled on the server. I see no reason why your quoted code would result in the $discounts array being modified. Either Register Globals is enabled or you're messing up somewhere else.

Comment: If I understand this Register Globals correctly, then it probably isn't the culprit here, because `$discounts` changes during one of the iterations of the loop.

Comment: Check by using the code: if (ini_get('register_globals') == 1){ echo 'ON'; }